# How to style internal links on a website?

Tags: css

So having a big website with a lot of classes, how can I trigger the internal links on a particular div.

I have to escape the default behavior of browsers of highlighting everything so I use something like this:

```
a:link{color: inherit;}
a:active{color:inherit;}
a:visited{color:inherit;}
```

Further more, on the section of the page that I want to highlight links, external or internal I use:

```
.section a:link {color: #274123;}
```

That rule doesn't pick up internal links though. Is there a possibility to do this with another pseudo-class or something like that? I can't point to the href attribute since the hosting might change soon.

Comment: Not quite understanding what you're trying to do. Can you post a code example of your "internal link" html?

Comment: try this .section a:link { color:#274123!important; }.

Comment: @Mouloud You shouldn't use `!important` to compensate for lack of understanding the 'cascading' part of CSS.

Comment: any jsfiddle or link to check ?

Comment: Too much code to paste, I'll guess I'll have to rework the classes and use more specific rules.

Comment: oh and it's not internal links per se, I got that wrong, it's links that have no parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/9CrCg/1/.).

Basically if you want a DIV to escape the general browser, you add a class to your div. Then to change the links specific behavior for each div you would do `.divclass a:link{color:blue;}`

Comment: No I got that. What I'm saying is the behavior with the rules I mentioned in the OP makes no sense. Basically links with javascript calls in the href are highlighted, the ones with direct internal links to a php page don't, although if I check to see what rules are active in Firebug, it's correct.